# Which Proguard optimizations can I use that won't affect stacktrace readability

Tags: java, optimization, proguard

I would like to use more functions of Proguard for the project I am working on. We are using it already to strip unused methods and classes and feel pretty comfortable in that setup. We would like to explore using optimizations to further reduce the size and improve performance. However, I wouldn't like to significantly increase the maintenance cost and most importantly, I wouldn't like to make it harder to analyze our stacktraces. We depend on them to discover issues, therefore we don't want to introduce additional steps that obfuscation would incur and also would like to keep stacktraces match the code as much as possible.

I looked at the available optimizations and it seems that things like `class/merging/*` would make stacktraces differ from the actual code, while `method/marking/*` could be used without any stacktrace readability cost. Does anyone have experience with enabling proguard optimizations and choosing the ones that give the most benefit while incurring least cost?

Comment: The whole point of proguard is to make readability hard for reverse engineering. You can allow "line numbers" to make debugging easier. Also, it gives you the "mappings" to debug it.

Comment: My understanding was that proguard provides various functionalities: stripping code, obfuscation, optimizations. I would only need mappings and line numbers if I used the obfuscation part. I am looking for low cost use of the optimization part.

Comment: Yes, see here: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/.